# Homebrew : Error: openjdk@8: no bottle available

Tags: java, java-8, homebrew

I am trying to install Java 8 with OpenJDK in an M1 Macbook terminal and it gives the following error. Command that I used was `brew install openjdk@8`

```
Error: openjdk@8: no bottle available!

You can try to install from source with:
brew install --build-from-source openjdk@8
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, there is no version of openjdk@8 that supports M1 x64 bit chips in Macbooks. But, there is an alternative and it could be installed using this website : https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8